# Why Spark create less partitions than the number of files whem reading from S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm using Spark 2.3.1.

I have a job that reads 5.000 small parquet files into s3.

When I do a `mapPartitions` followed by a `collect`, only **278** tasks are used (I would have expected 5000). Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark is grouping multiple files into each partition due to their small size. You should see as much when you print out the partitions.

Example (Scala):

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/files")
df.rdd.partitions.foreach(println)
```

Comment: What is the threshold for grouping ? Is it configurable ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 5,000 task you could do a repartition transformation.

Quote from [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) about repartition:

> Reshuffle the data in the RDD randomly to create either more or fewer
>   partitions and balance it across them. This always shuffles all data
>   over the network.

I recommend you take a look at the [RDD Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations). Remember that shuffle is an expensive operation.